# Style a database search output

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

i need help to style the output when i use php and search for for example names in my database...

The output will just be default text like amateur echo...

This is my code, and a screenshot of my homepage where i want the output to come inside the div... and to be like the rest of the text?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contact">

            <h1>Indtast postnummer & få bynavn:</h1>
        <form action="select.php" method="POST">    
            Postnummer: <input type="text" name="formnavn"/>
           <input type="submit" value="SEND"/>
        </form>
            <form action="index.php">
                <input style="" type="submit" value="Startsiden">
            </form>
        </div>
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$brugernavn = "root";
$kode = "";
$db = "dbintro2f";
mysql_connect($server , $brugernavn , $kode);// or die(mysql_error());
//echo "Forbundet til mysql server<br/>";
mysql_select_db($db); //or die(mysql_error());

$postnr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'formnavn');
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM postnummer WHERE (postnr) = $postnr" ) or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
echo "Postnummer: " . $info['postnr'] . "<br/>";
echo "By: " . $info['bynavn']. "<br/>";
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The codes in netbeans
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7I4B.jpg

The webpage and used paint to show how i want it to be in a div below my search field.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MGvc.jpg

Comment: echo <div style="margin-left:60%">;                               echo "Postnummer: " . $info['postnr'] . "<br/>";
echo "By: " . $info['bynavn']. "<br/>"; echo "</div>";

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP was invented as template language, you are still free to use HTML whereever inside it like:

```
...
$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
?>
 <div class="mydiv">
<?php
echo "Postnummer: " . $info['postnr'] . "<br/>";
...
```

Three lines in the middle of snippet (including closing PHP tag `?>` and next opening `<?php`) are to output `<div>` on the page. When the parser encounters closing PHP tag, it stops treating the source as PHP code and starts to simply output it.

Hope it helps.